# How to run ntp commands as non-root?

Tags: root, ntp, ntpd

NTP commands such as `ntpd` and `ntpdate` are privileged and belongs to the root group. What is the best way to run these commands as non-root ? Linux capabilities, ownership, any method ? I have openSUSE 13.2 and I prefer if there is a Linux capability that would help (if applicable of course). I looked into into the Linux capabilities list, I have tried applying `CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE`, `CAP_SYS_ADMIN`, `CAP_SYS_RAWIO`, `CAP_SYS_TIME` to both `ntpd` and `ntpdate` and it did not work.

Answer (score 3):

This 2 configuration options should help you to make `ntpd` more secure:

```
NTPD_OPTIONS="-g -u ntp:ntp"
NTPD_RUN_CHROOTED="yes"
```

Explanation

- `NTPD_OPTIONS="-g -u ntp:ntp"` - `-g` sets once when starts to ntpd ignore the default threshold that is set to 1000 . `-u ntp:ntp` makes the daemon run as ntp user and group.
- `NTPD_RUN_CHROOTED="yes"` - Makes ntpd run [chrooted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot), reducing the damages caused by exploits.

Since ntpd is running as ntp user, and using ntpdate to adjust manually the time [is not a good practice](https://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Dev/DeprecatingNtpdate), i don't see why you have to bother with ntpdate. To force a manually query use `sudo ntpd -gq` and add the following to your `/etc/sudoers` file:

`your-username ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/ntpd -gq`

Comment: `-g` does not make "ntpd more secure." Instructing ntpd to ignore the panic threshhold does nothing to improve security, it just instructs ntpd to not be picky about time difference between local clock and remote time server.